# How can I understand this Python "def" code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sensors, adafruit-circuitpython

I do not understand this code:

```py
#Read temperature sensor

def Read_Temperature(places):

    humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT_.read_retry(sensor, pin)
   
    temperature = round(humidity, places)
    
    return temperature
```

Can you please tell me what this code means?

Comment: Questions seeking an understanding of a piece of code are OK here, but it helps a great deal to explain what you do know and what you don't. Some background is very useful too - where did you get the code? Did you try running it? Don't make readers do all the legwork!

Comment: i dont have idea of this code here, i just wanna know what these lines are and how they work. i got it from my friend and i was just curious on what's the meaning of that. i really appreciate from the bottom of my heart for those who helped me.

Comment: hi halfer i'm sorry i'm just new to this site. This lines of codes are all I want to understand, I really appreciate who helped me and sorry I didn't mean the readers to do all the legwork of my questions.

Answer (score 1):

```
humidity,temperature = Adafruit_DHT_.read_retry(sensor,pin)
```

This first instruction means the sensor will read the values of humidity and temperature a couple of time (which explain the read_retry). Reading the documentation, it will do so up to 15 times.

```
temperature = round(humidity,places)
```

For this one, I recommend reading the documentation you can find here : https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_round.asp . It's going to round the humidity value by the number of places

Then it simply give you the temperature.

Comment: hi Mizun0o! thanks for the answer!

Comment: how about this line?  "return temperature"

Comment: "return temperature" gives you back the value of the said temperature you just calculated !

Comment: thanks a lot Mizun0o, i finally understood this lines of codes all thanks to you sir!

Comment: Hi Minz0o, can i ask 1 more time what is the meaning of this line. "temperature_percentage = readtemperature(2)

Comment: Of course ! Temperature_percentage is a variable that will take the value that the method "readtemperature(2)" return (remember the temperature we talked about sooner ? It's the value !). The 2 in between the parenthesis is the value the parameter "places" will take in your code.

Comment: Mizun0o. why it is 2 though?